# Not following algebra in an inductive proof of the formula for the sum of consecutive cubes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I'm learning mathematical induction as a proof technique (teaching myself discrete math as a foundation for a comp sci class I'm going to be taking). My algebra is a little rusty, and I cannot follow how this proof gets to the second step of $(1/4)k^2(k+1)^2+(k+1)^3$. I'm also lost on how we get from line 2 to 3, where it goes from $(1/4)k^2(k+1)^2 + (k+1)^3$ to $(1/4)(k+1)^2[k^2+4(k+1)]$.

[image: proof]

Comment: It just distributes the square $\bigg[ \frac{k(k+1)}{2}\bigg]^2 = \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{2^2}$.

Comment: In general, $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}$. More generally still, $\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$.

Comment: Ah, cool. How does the 1/4 then get factored out?

Comment: $(\frac {1}{2} )^2 = \frac {1}{4}$.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. I forgot that (a/b)c = ac/b

Comment: Actually, how do we get from line 2 to line 3? I'm lost again on how the addition sign was dropped and we're left with [k^2+4(k+1)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added one line with some color

---

Now L.H.S. is
$$
\begin{align}
1^3+2^3+\dots+k^3+(k+1)^3
&=\left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2+(k+1)^3\\
&=\frac14k^2(k+1)^2+(k+1)^3\\
&=\frac14\color{#C00000}{k^2}(k+1)^2+\frac14(k+1)^2\color{#00A000}{4(k+1)}\\
&=\frac14(k+1)^2\left[\color{#C00000}{k^2}+\color{#00A000}{4(k+1)}\right]\\
&=\frac14(k+1)^2\left[k^2+4k+4\right]\\
&=\frac14(k+1)^2(k+2)^2\\
&=\left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right]^2
\end{align}
$$
Therefore L.H.S.=R.H.S

i.e. $\displaystyle1^3+2^3+\dots+k^3+(k+1)^3=\left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right]^2$

Comment: I apologize for sounding like a broken record, but be aware of the fact that about ten percent of the male population is colorblind to a greater or lesser degree. Blue is a fairly safe choice, but two colors, especially red and green, is less so.

Comment: @RickDecker: note that the color is simply an aid. The added line is broken down further to the point where the pieces simply need to be moved to the right spot.

Comment: The extra line made all the difference. I understand proof by induction, but the algebra to apply the inductive hypothesis is still tripping me up.